# Поместить элемент списка Bitmap'ов в PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеется список Bitmap'ов, есть GroupBox с 9 PictureBox внутри, необходимо последовательно поместить в каждый PictureBox  элемент из списка.

```
for (int i = 0; i < GbPazzlesBox.Controls.Count; i++)
       {
           ((PictureBox)GbPazzlesBox.Controls[i]).Image = OriginalPB[i];
       }
```

Использую вот такой код получаю ошибку компилятора "Не удается применить индексирование через [ ] к выражению типа "PictureBox" ". Подскажите как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Попробуйте взять в скобки `GbPazzlesBox.Controls[i]`. Ну то есть `((PictureBox)(GbPazzlesBox.Controls[i])).Image`

Comment: Ругается на правую часть выражения то есть `OriginalPB[i]`

Comment: Как ругается? Матом?

Comment: Дайте больше кода. Что у вас в OriginalPB всё-таки? И полный текст ошибки, не в пересказе

Comment: Исходя из ваших прошлых вопросов, `OriginalPB` - это PictureBox. Естественно, у него нет индексатора. / Вы же там коллекцию мелких картинок получаете, вот эта коллекция и должна быть.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я понял уже. Просто есть две похожие переменные, одна как раз - PictureBox, а вторая коллекция картинок.